# Collective noun for a group of healthy people?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What's a good word or expression to describe a group of people who:

- eat well
- exercise regularly
- generally take good physical care of themselves

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call them  *health-conscious* people.

Comment: +1 You could even use a noun form *the health-conscious*.